# Error when trying importing CSV file to online psql database

Tags: python, flask, psql

ERROR: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "isbn
 of relation "books" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, author, publicationyear) VAL...

```
PYTHON CODE: 

import csv
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *
from application import DATABASE_URL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = DATABASE_URL
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    f = open("books.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)              # skips the top line
    for isbn, title, author, date in reader:
        book = Book(isbn = isbn, title = title, author = author, publicationyear = int(date))
        db.session.add(book)
        print(f"Added book with {isbn}, title : {title}, author: {author}, publication year: {date}.")
    print("commiting")
    db.session.commit()
    print("committed all data")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        main()
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask properly a question. You should provide more information about your problem. A reproducible example with input and expected output, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: do you make migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that perhaps you are having a problem with your models file. The error is stating the `books` doesn't exist, are you sure you have created you books table? `db.create_all()` Your model should be where your table definitions are. I would recommend becoming comfortable using SQL commands before you start to use Python-Flask-SQLAlchemy. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Fergus. It was an issue with models. I corrected the code and it works.